# Adobe Photoshop CS 5.1 not working in Mojave via Parallels

Tags: mojave, gpu, parallels-desktop, compatibility, adobe-photoshop

I am trying to run Photoshop CS5.1 (from the Adobe CS 5.5 Web Premium suite) in MacOS 10.14 Mojave using Parallels. The host machine is a 15" MacBook Pro late 2013 with a 2GB nVidia GT750M GPU and running Catalina. However, when I try to run the program it briefly flashes the splash screen then I get an error saying it quit unexpectedly. Here is an excerpt of the error:

```
Process:               Adobe Photoshop CS5.1 [380]
Path:                  /Applications/Adobe Photoshop CS5.1/Adobe Photoshop CS5.1.app/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Photoshop CS5.1
Identifier:            com.adobe.Photoshop
Version:               12.1 (12.1x20110328.r.145] [12.1)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Adobe Photoshop CS5.1 [380]
User ID:               501
Date/Time:             2022-05-01 17:03:18.483 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.6 (18G103)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        34F192B4-EA33-C3C5-1CE6-A1D68E7455E1

Time Awake Since Boot: 110 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000 Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [380]

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000100000000-00000001026fc000 [ 39.0M] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Adobe Photoshop CS5.1/Adobe Photoshop CS5.1.app/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Photoshop CS5.1

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.opengl                0x00007fff385c6d79 CGLDescribeRenderer + 78
1   com.adobe.Photoshop             0x00000001008ca245 AWS_CUI_GetVersionComments(OpaqueWindowPtr*, adobe::q::QDocument&, adobe::q::QString&, adobe::q::QAttributeList&, adobe::q::QDocument*, adobe::q::QProject*, long) + 6217217
2   com.adobe.Photoshop             0x000000010072d32d AWS_CUI_GetVersionComments(OpaqueWindowPtr*, adobe::q::QDocument&, adobe::q::QString&, adobe::q::QAttributeList&, adobe::q::QDocument*, adobe::q::QProject*, long) + 4525801
3   com.adobe.Photoshop             0x000000010073bd7b AWS_CUI_GetVersionComments(OpaqueWindowPtr*, adobe::q::QDocument&, adobe::q::QString&, adobe::q::QAttributeList&, adobe::q::QDocument*, adobe::q::QProject*, long) + 4585783
4   com.adobe.Photoshop             0x000000010073bf6c AWS_CUI_GetVersionComments(OpaqueWindowPtr*, adobe::q::QDocument&, adobe::q::QString&, adobe::q::QAttributeList&, adobe::q::QDocument*, adobe::q::QProject*, long) + 4586280
5   com.adobe.Photoshop             0x0000000100628f00 AWS_CUI_GetVersionComments(OpaqueWindowPtr*, adobe::q::QDocument&, adobe::q::QString&, adobe::q::QAttributeList&, adobe::q::QDocument*, adobe::q::QProject*, long) + 3459772
6   com.adobe.Photoshop             0x000000010062a097 AWS_CUI_GetVersionComments(OpaqueWindowPtr*, adobe::q::QDocument&, adobe::q::QString&, adobe::q::QAttributeList&, adobe::q::QDocument*, adobe::q::QProject*, long) + 3464275
7   com.adobe.Photoshop             0x00000001006b4a45 AWS_CUI_GetVersionComments(OpaqueWindowPtr*, adobe::q::QDocument&, adobe::q::QString&, adobe::q::QAttributeList&, adobe::q::QDocument*, adobe::q::QProject*, long) + 4032001
8   com.adobe.Photoshop             0x0000000100236e15 0x100000000 + 2321941
9   com.adobe.Photoshop             0x0000000100237229 0x100000000 + 2322985
10  com.adobe.Photoshop             0x0000000100002294 0x100000000 + 8852
```

From this information I believe this is some sort of OpenGL issue resulting from running in Parallels rather than a general compatibility problem with this version of Photoshop and the OS. Numerous people have reported CS 5.5 mostly working fine on Mojave when installing from scratch, and I have already followed some documented steps to make it work:

- Installed legacy Java runtime
- Gone to system security settings and allowed app to control computer and have full disk access

I also noticed that Dreamweaver works to an extent and this is probably due to it not being so reliant on hardware acceleration

I already contacted Parallels support by email and their suggestion was to increase CPU and RAM allocation, but the VM already has 2 CPU cores and 4GB assigned.

I could maybe try using an older OS for the VM but I don’t want to risk wasting a load of time without knowing if it will work any better. If anyone has encountered similar problem and found a workaround please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creative Suite 5.5 is 2011 vintage. If you're going to run it in a VM, then I'd suggest something of a similar age, so either Mountain Lion or Mavericks.

That will ensure better compatibility, and an OS of that vintage will also use fewer resources than Mojave from 2018.

Otherwise, you might as well stay on Mojave in the 'real' MBP.

However, I'd really recommend that you just cut your losses and buy [Affinity Photo](https://affinity.serif.com/en-gb/photo/) (also Affinity Designer and Publisher if you need Illustrator and InDesign alternatives). "There comes a point when..."

Comment: I already purchased Affinity Photo but have never been that comfortable using it due to some of its quirks. I may try an older OS but I’m not clear if it will solve the problem, since according to many separate sources, Adobe CS 5.5 *can* work reasonably with Mojave at least when running directly on hardware. I bought Parallels for this scenario and I don’t see a good reason why this shouldn’t work. Plus I don’t want to have to run an OS older than necessary (particularly on the host) due to the increased security risks

Comment: @James You should be reasonably protected from security threats by the host OS -- unless you're browsing in the VM. It also has to be said that MBPs with discrete GPUs have a long history of flakiness.

Comment: 4GB is nowhere near enough to run Mojave. Try 8 or 16 & switch off all graphics acceleration in Ps. Also, CS6 isn't qualified for Mojave, 5 certainly isn't.

Comment: @Tejutsin: Apple's own documentation lists 2GB RAM as the minimum (https://support.apple.com/kb/SP777) so 4GB should be fine. Nevertheless I increased it to 8GB and there was no change. I'm unable to turn off hardware acceleration as Photoshop will not even open. I'm going to try El Capitan instead but I'm not convinced it will necessarily solve the problem

Comment: Well that was a waste of time, El Capitan simply refuses to install in Parallels

Comment: @James Try VMware Fusion (free for personal use) - it is arguably better than Parallels for macOS/OSX clients.

Comment: @Gilby: After a lot of faffing around I eventually I got El Capitan to successfully  install in VMWare but it is ridiculously slow due to lack of hardware acceleration. I'm about done with any kind of MacOS virtualisation at this point

Comment: @James Unless you can give it multiple cores and lots of RAM, then yes, VMs will be slow. I ran CS6 in Mavericks in Parallels, and then ran the El Capitan installer inside the VM; but it was still slow in a 6-core 2018 Mini.

Comment: I have several El Capitan instance running here in Parallels - in fact, OSes from Snow Leo upwards all work fine, base OS is Mojave… but I'm running them on a Mac Pro with 64GB RAM & a far more powerful GPU.

Comment: @benwiggy: I decided to give Parallels one more chance with El Capitan and inexplicably it succeeded in installing this time. It's not exactly fast but just about usable I think and Photoshop does at least work. But I'm beginning to think maybe I should just sell CS 5.5 and get used to Affinity instead

Comment: @James I'd be surprised if anyone would buy CS 5 for meaningful money. It's verging on 'hobbyist retro'. ;-) Affinity is a bit quirky, but it's fast, works, and is being developed...!